# Serializing to model - serialize node to choice of two objects

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a JSON file of following structure.

```
{
    title: {
        title: "",
        episode_title: ""
    },
    series: {
        season: "",
        episode: ""
    }
    content_description: {
        ???
    }
}
```

, where content_description may have one of following formats:

```
content_description: {
    language: "",
    short_synapsis: "",
    medium_synopsis: "",
    long_synopsis: "",
    oneliner: ""
}

OR

content_description: {
    text: "",
    category: "",
    level: "", 
    source: ""
}
```

I want to serialize it to C# model using Newtonsoft Json.NET JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(string value) method. So far, I've created a following content_description model:

```
public class ContentDescriptions
{
    public string language { get; set; }
    public string short_synopsis { get; set; }
    public string medium_synopsis { get; set; }
    public string long_synopsis { get; set; }
    public string short_season_synopsis { get; set; }
    public string medium_season_synopsis { get; set; }
    public string long_season_synopsis { get; set; }
    public string short_episode_synopsis { get; set; }
    public string medium_episode_synopsis { get; set; }
    public string long_episode_synopsis { get; set; }
    public string oneliner { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
    public string category { get; set; }
    public string level { get; set; }
    public string source { get; set; }
}
```

This works, but is there a way to serialize element with one name to one of two models depending if its structure? For example, having two content_description model fields in my root model and filling one of them while leaving the other one null?

Comment: One cannot serialize JSON to anything, because JSON itself is a result of serialization. It isn't clear, what is your exact question. Do you have a code sample, which doesn't work as expected?

Comment: try to convert the result to an anonymous object or dynamic then look for one of the fields which is not repeated on another model, then decide to choose which model to choose and convert.

Comment: @Aegonek Please share with us your json file as well. Also please try to share with us how did you try to tackle this problem and where did you stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Would a container class work?

```
class MyAmazingClass {
  ContentDescriptionsA A {get; set;}
  ContentDescriptionsB B {get; set;}
}
```

and then you could (de)serialise object of this class.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly from your limited amount of information you expect to get a json string that can be either A or B. You are nog interested in B as it can be instantiated with null values or empty.

In that case you can deserialize with object A (ContentDescriptionsA) everytime. The properties of the class will be filled whena JsonString with contents of A come through and the properties will be null if an object of B comes through.

Here's a simple Console application that you can rebuild to play around with the concept. (Sidenote: you could also create a class that holds ALL the properties of both JsonStrings, but then the properties of B will also be filled)

```
using System.Text.Json;

namespace TestJson
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var a = new ContentDescriptionsA() { language = "NederlandsA"};
        var b = new ContentDescriptionsB() { text = "TextB" };

        var jsonstringA = JsonSerializer.Serialize(a);
        var jsonstringB = JsonSerializer.Serialize(b);


        var deserializeA = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ContentDescriptionsA>(jsonstringA); // properties of a FILLED, props of b NULL
        var deserializeB = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ContentDescriptionsA>(jsonstringB); // all properties NULL
    }
}

public class ContentDescriptionsA
{
    public string language { get; set; }
    public string short_synopsis { get; set; }
    public string medium_synopsis { get; set; }
    public string long_synopsis { get; set; }
    public string short_season_synopsis { get; set; }
    public string medium_season_synopsis { get; set; }
    public string long_season_synopsis { get; set; }
    public string short_episode_synopsis { get; set; }
    public string medium_episode_synopsis { get; set; }
    public string long_episode_synopsis { get; set; }
    public string oneliner { get; set; }
}
public class ContentDescriptionsB
{
    public string text { get; set; }
    public string category { get; set; }
    public string level { get; set; }
    public string source { get; set; }
}
}
```